# Default application not respected—cause/fix?

Tags: finder, music, shortcut-menu

I have an album in Music.app with 21 .m4a files and two .mp3.  The .m4a were purchased from Apple.  The other two were purchased but converted to MP3 by [Amadeus Pro](https://hairersoft.com/pro.html).  Default opener for **all** .m4a is set to Amadeus Pro.  "Normally" it would be Music.app but I changed it so that I could edit audio more easily.

Twenty of these files open as expected in Amadeus.  One of the purchased files is weird.  The context menu and the Get Info pop-up say that the default opener is Amadeus, but

- double-click
- open with
- `open` (in shell)
- `open -a (Amadeus path)` in shell

all get a pop-up saying that **QuickTime** can't open it, but showing the Amadeus icon:

[image]

If I use File→Open in Amadeus Pro, I get the same pop-up!

**What is the cause and/or fix?**

`wc` showed that it was an actual file (not a store placeholder)

`ls -late@` showed that it was the only file in the directory with extended attributes (and no ACL) but after removing them, the error still occurred.

`file` showed that it had ID3 tags while the other .m4a did not.

I deleted the file from library and directory.  Music then said the file "could not be found."  But it did not show as available for download.  So I double-clicked the name in "Purchased files" and it began playing.  A new copy was in the album directory that did **not** have ID3 tags but the error still happened on it.

Track ten is the one that’s still weird after fetching fresh from the store.  Playback works, so the file contents must not be significantly corrupted.

```
WGroleau@MBP Colección de Oro % file *
01 Mi Nuevo Amor.m4a:            ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio
02 Árbol Sin Raices.m4a:         ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio
03 Necesito de Ti.m4a:           ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio
04 Elevo Mi Canción.m4a:         ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio
05 Libertad.m4a:                 ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio
06 Mi Palomita.m4a:              ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio
07 Levantate.m4a:                ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio
08 Ungeme.m4a:                   ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio
09 Magnifico.m4a:                ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio
10 Confío en Dios.m4a:           ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio
11 Tengo Fe.m4a:                 ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio
12 Te daré.m4a:                  ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio
13 Confesión.m4a:                ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio
14 Cada Mañana.m4a:              ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio
15 Unos a Otros.m4a:             ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio
16 Mi Vida Está Llena de Ti.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0
17 Creyendo en Ti.m4a:           ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio
18 Actualidad.m4a:               ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio
19 Tengo Vida Nueva.m4a:         ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio
20 Jesús y el Leproso.m4a:       ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio
21 Jesús de Nazareth.mp3:        Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0
22 Anoche Llegaste Tarde.m4a:    ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio
23 Soy un Soldado.m4a:           ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio
```

Comment: If you run `file` for the problematic track and for a good one, what is the result?

Comment: Just added that info and more to the text.

Comment: Please copy/paste the output you got as text (and indicate which file is which), too much may get lost by paraphrasing.

Answer (score 1):

I examined the metadata with [exiftool](https://exiftool.org) and found that the weird file has Sort Album & Sort Artist attributes.  I’ve never had a reason to change the "Sorting" tab on any song, and certainly didn’t after the fresh download.

But when I deleted those attributes on the Music Get Info pop-up, the weirdness went away.  I’m going to call this an Apple bug.